# Desktop effects (compiz) turned on: How to capture the image of a window WITH border/frame/title bar?

Tags: linux, screenshot, xlib

I would like to get the image of an X server Window (toplevel window, parent is the root Window) with its border/frame/title bar. I have already tried several libraries (Xlib, XRender, gdk, cairo) but none of them works. The captured image has the same geometry as the window but the frame is missing.

The problem is that the child window which should hold the frame image is InputOnly. The reason might be for this that the frame is rendered by the window decorator on the fly the same time as the Window itself.

I cannot capture the image from the RootWindow as the Window might be partially or entirely covered.

Redecorating the captured Window image could be an alternative.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

PS. When compiz is not running everything works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I use shutter for screen shots on linux, it's super easy to capture whatever portion of the screen you want. As a bonus, there are tools to add arrows or highlight sections.

http://shutter-project.org/preview/screenshots/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this neither a solution which could be used from a program nor it is working for a partially covered window.

Comment: I see, I did not realize you were trying to do it from a program. As far as a partially covered window, one of the choices on the panel is "Select a Window with your mouse", this will only capture whichever window you choose, including border, frame, and title bar. It works even if entire window is behind another.